# Perl on Linux: change locale for subprocesses

Tags: linux, perl, subprocess, locale

What is the correct way to change the locale for a subprocess (in Linux)?

Example, when running

```
perl -e 'use POSIX qw(setlocale); setlocale(POSIX::LC_ALL, "C"); open F, "locale|"; while (<F>) { print if /LC_MESS/ }; close F'
```

I get the answer `LC_MESSAGES="ca_ES.UTF-8"` but I would like to obtain `LC_MESSAGES="C"`. Whatever I've tried I can't seem to change it.

Note: I know about doing `LC_ALL=C perl .....` but this is **not** what I want todo, I neet to **change the locale inside the Perl script**.

Comment: `$ENV{LC_ALL} = 'C';` may do the job.

Comment: See also [perldoc perllocale](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, that does the job. Did not think of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm picking up on [Ted Lyngmo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66706385/perl-on-linux-change-locale-for-subprocesses/66707882#comment117918074_66706385), so credit goes to him.

You can set the environment for your code as well as subsequent sub-processes with `%ENV`. As with all global variables, it makes sense to only change these locally, temporarily, for your scope and smaller scopes. That's what `local` does.

I've also changed your `open` to use the three-arg form as that's more secure (even though you're not using a variable for the filename/command), and used a lexical filehandle. The lexical handle will go out of scope at the end of the block and `close` implicitly.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(setlocale);

{
    setlocale(POSIX::LC_ALL, "C");
    local $ENV{LC_ALL} = 'C';

    open my $fh, '-|', 'locale' or die $!;
    while (<$fh>) {
        print if /LC_MESS/
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work. Also, I could not find in the doc how to do the three arg form when opening a pipe from a subprocess, good to know!